# How can I get the name of the current __package__ of the subclass in the base class in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

I have a base class `BaseConsumer`, in package `common`, that initializes logging as follows:

**common/base.py**:

```
class BaseConsumer():
   def __init__(self):
      self.logger = logging.getLogger(f'{__package__}.{self.__class__.__name__}')
   ...
```

Now, in package `stash`, when I use subclass `BaseConsumer`, a `Logger` is created called `common.Consumer` instead of `stash.Consumer`:

**stash/consumer.py**:

```
class Consumer(BaseConsumer):
   ...
```

How can I make `logging.getLogger(f'{__package__}.{self.__class__.__name__}')` generic, so that `__package__` is changed to the name of the package of the subclass, (in this case `stash`)?

NB: I've tried to get the package name of the subclass through `self`, but that information seems not to be available through it?

Comment: Why `__package__`? That doesn't look right. Are you sure you're not looking for `__module__`? (Also `__qualname__` instead of `__name__`.)

Comment: But `self` doesn't have a `__qualname__` attribute. And why would I use `__module__` instead of `__package__`?

Comment: The class is `stash.consumer.Consumer`, not `stash.Consumer`.